# TFS errors: Missing tons of .gz files. Causes asp DLLs to crash

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tfs, asp.net-identity, owin

I have been having strange problems lately with Identity/OWIN on a specific project. I'm using TFS with a colleague of mine and the strange thing is he is not experiencing any of these problems. I have erased my project and got latest, tried my secondary laptop, and finally a friend's pc but am still getting errors.

The first error dealt with owin and would crash on any page before the page even rendered. It seemed to be some issue with cookies and a null reference in an owin method of Cookie.Next or something of the sort. I cleared my cookies which seemed to have fixed the problem. The new problem I am getting is:

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entitySet

This is occurring when I try to login. Here is the exact line I get from the error page.

```
Line 50:             if (ModelState.IsValid)
Line 51:             {
Line 52:                 var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Username, model.Password);
Line 53:                 if (user != null)
Line 54:                 {
```

**The error occurs on line 52**

I traced the error line by line and the last line that gets executed prior to blowing up is in the account controller. It's default MVC project code.

```
 protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && UserManager != null)
        {
            UserManager.Dispose();
            UserManager = null;
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Code executes through that whole method but after pressing F11 on `base.Dispose(disposing)` I get the above error message. The stacktrace points to it being an internal dll problem; however, I find this hard to believe because I cannot find any trace of this happening to anyone before.

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entitySet]
System.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotNull(T value, String parameterName) +68
System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.EntitySetMapping..ctor(EntitySet entitySet, EntityContainerMapping containerMapping) +74
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.DbDatabaseMappingExtensions.AddEntitySetMapping(DbDatabaseM apping databaseMapping, EntitySet entitySet) +67
System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.TableMappingGenerator.Generate(EntityType entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping) +194
  System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.GenerateEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping) +422
System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.Generate(EdmModel conceptualModel) +65
 System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.EdmModelExtensions.GenerateDatabaseMapping(EdmModel model, DbProviderInfo providerInfo, DbProviderManifest providerManifest) +73
  System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo) +476
  System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) +103
  System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) +143
  System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +171
  System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +594
  System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +31
  System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +39
  System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +137
  System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Include(String path) +41
  System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.Include(String path) +142
  System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include(IQueryable`1 source, String path) +205
  System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 path) +305
  Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.GetUserAggregateAsync(Expression`1 filter) +610
  Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.FindByNameAsync(String userName) +1072
  Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.FindByNameAsync(String userName) +177
  Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<FindAsync>d__12.MoveNext() +171
  System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
  System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
  System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
  Jdmxchange_V3.Controllers.<Login>d__8.MoveNext() in c:\Users\chuyita\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Jdmxchange_V3\Jdmxchange_V3\Controllers\AccountController.cs:52
  System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
  System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
  System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
  System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task) +61
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +114
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +66
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +117
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +323
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +72
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
  System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
  System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
  System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
  System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
  System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
  System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
  System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
  System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
  System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651116
  System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

### Update 1 - 11/17/2014

We have taken multiple steps to troubleshoot the problems which are as follows:

1. My partner copied his project files to a backup location, deleted his source, and got latest directly from TFS (He had no problems and was able to run)
2. I did the exact same and was unable to run
3. I got a fresh new copy downloaded to 2 fresh computers and still had the issue
4. My partner sent me his whole source folder via one drive and I tried to run it on my machine. (This worked)
5. I downloaded winmerge and compared my source from TFS with the source he sent me from one drive and there were too many differences in the folders to go through. Most differences seemed to be tied to tfs files with a .gz extension. My tfs source did not have these while the source he sent me via one drive did.

I used win merge to merge all the files missing from my tfs and now my tfs source works properly. I cannot say what will happen when I check in or get latest but I will update this as I progress with this problem. I still don't know the cause of the problem but at least I know it's due to tfs.

Comment: Can you make sure he is checking-in at the solution level and not at the project level? I have had issues like this in the pass and it was just some reference or edmx not getting brought along during check in because someone checked in at the project level.

Comment: That is a good point. That would make complete sense as to why he isn't experiencing any errors while I am.

Comment: Chris, as per your suggestion I double checked to make sure he was checking in at the solution level. That did not seem to be the problem. I did however make some progress. I updated the post to reflect this. The issue seems to be fixed; however, I do not know if it will remain fixed for long.